# Error during migration of rule projects from 7.5 to 8.10.5

Tags: ibm-odm

After migrating of rule projects from 7.5 to 8.10.5, during extraction of ruleset, error is throwing as below.

> "An error occured during exporting of ruleset archive. While applying of Business to execution(B2X) model mapping GBREX0001E: cannot find execution class "XOM class path" for translating Business class "BOM class path".

I have checked references with complete BOM class path, there are no any java class associated neither in XOM nor in BOM. Because the path which its showing in error window, itself does not exist in workspace. Kindly assist

Tried referencing BOM class in the method arguments. It threw error while exporting ruleset.

Expecting that the ruleset should extract without any error.

Answer (score 0):

the message you have states that Java classes that backs up your BOM model are not found.

Did you check the dependencies in the rule project where your BOM is ?
You should find the java project/lib (that contains your classes) referenced in the "Java execution Model" in project->preferences-> Java execution Model

Hope this helps,
Emmanuel

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. As per your suggestion, I checked Java class references. It looks good. I checked in old projects. This kind of error is present there as well but its not showstopper but in migrated rule projects, this error is not allowing to export ruleset.

Comment: maybe try to deactivate the "export xom" checkbox in the deployment ?

Answer (score 0):

Select the '
'Decision Engine' option under the 'Rule Engine' option under the Eclipse-> Rule Project -> Properties. Setting this property should remove those errors from the Rule Designer